# Get the ng-content of ng-template from a component into another component

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I know there are other ideas, but I want to use `ng-template`, `ng-content` and `@ContenChild()` decorator in below defined manner.
The idea of such came by seeing actual implement of angular material components.

Here, I have two components:

1. Container component (app-container)
2. Child component (app-child)

I want to get the content of app-child component directly shown in app-container.

I have got some related solution here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngtemplateoutlet-and-content-projection?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. But this doesn't exactly fulfill my requirement.

Following html is desired, mainly in `app.component.html`:

```
<app-container>
   <app-nav>
       <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
       <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
   </app-nav>
  <app-main>
    <p>This is the content to be reflect.</p>
  </app-main>
</app-container>
```

Which should produce output like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
             <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
             <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
        </nav>
        <section role="main" class="main__content">
               <p>This is the content to be reflect.</p>
        </section>
</div>
```

My codes look like this

```
import { Component, ContentChild, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main'
    template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`
})
export class AppMain {

}
@Component({
    selector: 'app-nav'
    template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`
})
export class AppNav {

}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-container',
    template: `
               <div class="container">
                      <nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
                         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet="nav"></ng-container>
                      </nav>
                      <section role="main" class="main__content">
                         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="main"></ng-container>
                      </section>
               </div>
              `
})
export class AppContainer implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChild(AppMain) main: AppMain;
    @ContentChild(AppNav) nav: AppNav;

    ngAfterContentInit() {       
        console.log(this.main);
        console.log(this.nav);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not using selectable `ng-content` instead of `ng-container[ngTemplateOutlet]` inside `app-container`? I think it's more intuitive... but of course it can be just matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma615128146433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I think you'd get a cleaner structure by not using `ngTemplateOutlet`. IMO, you don't even need any `ng-template` element. Of course, I don't know your final goal, but you could do what I show below which is very similar to what you have, but I think the selectable `ng-content`'s in `app-container` makes the overall structure more intuitive and easier to understand the component's tree setup though:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-main",
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})

export class AppMain {}
@Component({
  selector: "app-nav",
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class AppNav {}

@Component({
  selector: "app-container",
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
        <ng-content select="[nav-slot]"></ng-content>
      </nav>
      <section role="main" class="main__content">
        <ng-content select="[main-slot]"></ng-content>
      </section>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppContainer {
  @ContentChild(AppMain) main: AppMain;
  @ContentChild(AppNav) nav: AppNav;

  ngAfterContentInit() { /* ... */}
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```html
<app-container>
    <app-nav nav-slot>
        <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
        <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
    </app-nav>
    <app-main main-slot>
        <p>This is the content to be reflect.</p>
    </app-main>
</app-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!!

Actually, to the get the content of any component, we can use `@ViewChild()` decorator.
So, for both `app-nav` and `app-main` components, i used same technique as shown below:

```
import { Component, ContentChild, AfterContentInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`
})
export class AppMain{
    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<any>;
}
@Component({
    selector: 'app-nav',
    template: `<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>`
})
export class AppNar {
    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) content: TemplateRef<any>;

}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-container',
    template: `
               <div class="container">
                      <nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
                         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet="nav.content"></ng-container>
                      </nav>
                      <section role="main" class="main__content">
                         <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="main.content"></ng-container>
                      </section>
               </div>
              `
})
export class AppContainer implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChild(AppMain) main: AppMain;
    @ContentChild(AppNav) nav!: AppNav;

    ngAfterContentInit() {

    }

}
```

So, while in `app.component.html`, I had:

```
<app-container>
   <app-nav>
       <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
       <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
   </app-nav>
  <app-main>
    <p>This is the content to be reflect.</p>
  </app-main>
</app-container>
```

And the output I got is actually the desired one:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav role="navigation" class="navigation">
             <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
             <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
        </nav>
        <section role="main" class="main__content">
               <p>This is the content to be reflect.</p>
        </section>
</div>
```